# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2+n}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

Wolfram Alpha shows that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2+n}=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
I want to prove this.

**Attempt:**

I tried to treat this as a telescoping series:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2+n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}H_n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=H_{1}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)+H_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+H_{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
&=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{12}
\end{align}$$
I think this method is not quite useful, so I tried  another one:
$$H_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt$$
Then,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^2+n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+n}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-t^n}{1-t}dt$$
At this point, I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: It should work similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506110/show-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frach-n2nn1-3-zeta3-where?rq=1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beside telescoping, all you need is to reverse the order of the double sum: $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{k\ge 1}k^{-1}\sum_{n\ge k}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{k\ge 1}k^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$Edit to explain the reversal: we're summing all terms of the form $\frac{k^{-1}}{n(n+1)}$ with $n,\,k$ integers in the set $\{(n,\,k)|n,\,k\ge 1,\,k\le n\}$. But I could equivalently describe this set as $\{(n,\,k)|k\ge 1,\,n\ge k\}$.

Comment: How do you reverse the order? I do not completely understand, especially how you manipulate the lower limit.

Comment: @Larry See edit.

Comment: $\frac{H_n}{n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})}=\frac{1}{n^2}lim_{n→∞}\frac{H_n}{1+H_n}=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: @J.G Thanks, I think I understand the reversal now.

Comment: @sirous Your equality is not true: for example $$H_1/(1^2+1)\neq 1/1^2$$

Comment: @sirous I don't understand what you're trying to say there, but even if you can obtain a valid asymptotic form for these terms it won't get you the exact sum.

Answer (score 8):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2+n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^n\frac1m\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1m\sum_{n=m}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)
\\&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac1m\cdot\frac1m
\\&=\frac{\pi^2}6.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

applying summation by parts
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{H_{n}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{H_n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_{n}}{n}-\frac{H_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=-\frac{H_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}
letting $N$ approach $\infty$, we get,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}=0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\zeta(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}$Starting with a [generating function for the Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions)

> $$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}~=~\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n\tag1$$

we divide both sides by $x$ and integrate afterwards to get

$$\small\begin{align*}
\int-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\mathrm dx&=\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^{n-1}\mathrm dx\\
\Li_2(x)+\frac12\log^2(1-x)+c&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}nx^{n}
\end{align*}$$

Plug in $x=0$ to determine the value of $c$ which turns out to be $0$ aswell. Integrating this equation yields to

$$\small\begin{align*}
\int\Li_2(x)+\frac12\log^2(1-x)\mathrm dx&=\int\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}nx^{n}\mathrm dx\\
x\Li_2(x)-x+(x-1)\log(1-x)+\frac12(x-1)(\log^2(1-x)-2\log(1-x)+2)+c&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}x^{n}
\end{align*}$$

The new constant again equals $0$ due the same argumentation as above. Now we can plug in $x=1$ to compute the value of your given series which overall is given by $\Li_2(1)$ and this is [well-known to equal $\zeta(2)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html).

> $$\therefore~\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}~=~\frac{\pi^2}6\tag2$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) we have $$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{H_{n}}{n\left(n+1\right)}=H_{N}\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}-\sum_{n\leq N-1}\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\sum_{k\leq n}\frac{1}{k\left(k+1\right)}\right).$$ Clearly $$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{n\left(n+1\right)}=\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)$$ then $$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{H_{n}}{n\left(n+1\right)}=H_{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N+1}\right)-H_{N}+\sum_{n\leq N-1}\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^{2}}.$$ Now, since $H_{N}\sim\log\left(N\right)$ as $N\rightarrow+\infty$, the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another, slightly longer, approach. It will use a double integral in order to evaluate the sum.

Noting that
$$\int_0^1 x^{n - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^1 y^n \, dy = \frac{1}{n + 1},$$
the sum can be written as
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n + 1)} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H_n (xy)^n \, dx dy.\tag1$$
Here the order of the summation with the double integral has been changed and can be done due to the dominated convergence theorem.

Making use of the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions) for the Harmonic number, namely
$$-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1 - x}~=~\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n x^n,$$
the infinity sum appearing inside the integral in (1) can be written as
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n + 1)} = -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - xy)}{x(1 - xy)} \, dx dy.$$
Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x/y$ gives
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n(n + 1)} &= -\int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{\ln (1 - x)}{x (1 - x)} \, dx dy\\
&= -\int_0^1 \int_0^y \left [\frac{\ln (1 - x)}{x} + \frac{\ln (1 - x)}{1 - x} \right ] \, dx \, dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_2 (y) \, dy + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \ln^2 (1 - y) \, dy\\
&= I_1 + \frac{1}{2} I_2.
\end{align}
Here $\operatorname{Li}_2 (y)$ is the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function).

For the first of these integrals, writing the dilogarithm function in terms of its series representation, we have
\begin{align}
I_1 &= \int_0^1 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{y^n}{n^2} \, dy\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \int_0^1 y^n \, dy\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2(n + 1)}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left [\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n} \right ]\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n + 1} \right )\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1,
\end{align}
where the first of the series is the well-known Basel problem while the second telescopes.

For the second of the integrals, define
$$I(a) = \int_0^1 (1 - y)^a \, dy, \quad a > - 1.$$
Observe that
$$I''(0) = \int_0^1 \ln^2 ( 1 - y) \, dy,$$
where the derivative is with respect to $a$. Now, as
$$I(a) = \operatorname{B} (1, a + 1) = \frac{\Gamma (a + 1)}{\Gamma (a + 2)} = \frac{1}{a + 1},$$
where $\operatorname{B}(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), one readily has
$$I''(a) = \frac{2}{(a + 1)^3},$$
yielding $I''(0) = I_2 = 2$.

Thus
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n (n + 1)} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$